# Is there a content length limit on the selection and drop register "+?

Tags: register, os-clipboard

When selecting about two dozens of lines in vim and copying it to the system register ("+ y), and then paste it into another vim, it crashes. It does not paste the content of the register and the terminal window (gnome-terminal) stucks.

If I have just a few lines to copy, everything works fine. The problem feels like there is a limit of some sort on the amount of characters to copy and paste. This cannot be.

Any insight or suggestions what might be the problem?

.vimrc

```
set number
set viminfo='100,<100,s10,h 
"set hlsearch

"to start the vi in insert mode  
:startinsert

"blocks comment 
"select with SHIFT+v and than hit # (for uncomment -#)
vnoremap # :s#^#\##<cr>
vnoremap -# :s#^\###<cr>

"leave "+ regitry available for the system after closing vi
autocmd VimLeave * call system("xsel -ib", getreg('+'))
"requires xsel 

set mouse=a
```

vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 2 2014 19:39:47)
Included patches: 1-52
Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax         
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary     
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static 
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white  
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl            
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo       
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse   
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects    
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title          
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar        
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands  
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit      
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit    
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual         
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra    
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo        
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace       
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore     
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu       
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +windows        
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup    
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11            
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset       
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim            
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact  
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save     
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    +xpm
```